# Pyomo: portfolio optimization with one constraint is ignored

Tags: python, pyomo, energy

thanks for your time.
It's an energy portfolio optimization problem.My code could run and output a result.But one key constraint doesn't work at all. So the result is wrong.

Backgrounds:

1. the shape of wind or solar generation is given, but capacity of wind or solar is unknown.
2. capacity of wind has a given upper limit, so does solar.
3. capacity of channel to transfer power generation is fixed, hydro's generation must be all transferred, so parts of the generation of wind and solar may be abounded.
4. total abounded generation of wind and solar should not account for more than 10%（this is the one doesn't work）.
5. the object is to find out the certain numbers of wind's and solar's capacity, which should satisfy all constraints and generate maximum transferred power production. Especially, the abounded generation percentage should be no more than 10%.

The result shows that capacity of wind = MaxW, capacity of solar = MaxS, and the percentage of abounded generation is about 86%.
I have been struggling to solve this bug for days but still very confused. Please help me out.

【Problem solved】 It turns out that I made a wrong print. Thanks.

Comment: see my edits...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of missing pieces here, and I'm not sure what you are getting out of that because it has syntax errors.

You *cannot* use `10%` to represent the decimal 0.10.  Just use the decimal value.  And it certainly cannot be a parameter of your function, as it is an illegal variable name.  ??

Typically "capacity" is a parameter (fixed value), not a variable.  ???

Fix it up, clean it up, and if you are still stuck, you can edit your code above (include some data so that a person helping you can cut/paste/run the whole enchilada).

#### EDIT (after your edit):

Ok, that is a bit more clear.  It still isn't clear where you attempt to make the total of wind + solar limited to 10% of total.

In constraint `m.abo_c1` you appear to be constraining the total of wind + solar to be at least 90% of the aggregate capacity you want to build, right?  If that is not your intent, you should revisit that constraint

So in *another* constraint, you need to impose the upper limit on wind and solar and if you have (in pseudocode):

```
wind + solar + hydro = tot_power
```

and you want:

```
wind + solar <= 0.1 x tot_power
```

Then you just need a little algebra to rearrange that to:

```
wind + solar <= 0.9 x hydro
```

I don't see that type of constraint in your model

Comment: Hi AirSquid, thanks a lot for your suggestions! Sorry that I didn't make it clear about the problems. There are two kinds of power. First, according to the capacity(Var to be found), we get the theoretical wind_power = capacity1  * shape of wind, solar_power=capacity2 * shape of solar. Then, because of the limitation of channel, wind_to transfer + solar_to transfer + hydro <= MaxChannel.  I want to control the difference between transferred power and theoretical power less than 10%. i.e.,  total (wind_power-wind_to transfer + solar_power-solar_to transfer)/total (wind_power+solar_power) <= 10%

Comment: Well, I checked the code again. It turns out that I made a wrong output. The model itself is correct... Thanks again for your help.